# Compare and group HH:MM value in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, datetime, case

How can I group datetime value using CASE statement into different shifts with time format HH:MM? The issue being that the differents shifts are spanning over a 24 hour schedule. Please see below:

```
   CREATE TABLE testData (
          [item_id] nvarchar(35) NOT NULL
        ,[event_time] datetime2(7) NULL
        ,[location_id] nvarchar(10) NULL
        ,[start_time_shift_1]nvarchar(5) NULL
        ,[stop_time_shift_1]nvarchar(5) NULL
        ,[start_time_shift_2]nvarchar(5) NULL
        ,[stop_time_shift_2]nvarchar(5) NULL
        ,[start_time_shift_3]nvarchar(5) NULL
        ,[stop_time_shift_3]nvarchar(5) NULL
      );
      
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[testData](
          [item_id]
        ,[event_time]
        ,[location_id]
        ,[start_time_shift_1]
        ,[stop_time_shift_1]
        ,[start_time_shift_2]
        ,[stop_time_shift_2]
        ,[start_time_shift_3]
        ,[stop_time_shift_3])
      
      VALUES
      ('1', '2021-08-18 08:26:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('2', '2021-08-23 20:20:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('3', '2021-08-21 03:24:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('4', '2021-08-20 00:38:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('5', '2021-08-20 06:10:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('6', '2021-08-20 05:42:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('7', '2021-08-23 21:37:00.0000000', '100','09:00','22:29','22:30','04:59','05:00','08:59')
      ,('8', '2021-08-23 21:37:00.0000000', '200','08:00','21:59','22:00','07:59',NULL,NULL)
      ,('9', '2021-08-19 04:10:00.0000000', '200','08:00','21:59','22:00','07:59',NULL,NULL)
      ,('10', '2021-08-20 01:09:00.0000000', '300','12:00','23:39','23:40','11:59',NULL,NULL)
      ,('11', '2021-08-24 07:14:00.0000000', '300','12:00','23:39','23:40','11:59',NULL,NULL)
      ,('12', '2021-08-24 16:57:00.0000000', '300','12:00','23:39','23:40','11:59',NULL,NULL)
      ;
      
      
      
      WITH CTE1 AS(
      SELECT
          [item_id]
        ,[event_time]
        ,CONVERT(varchar(5), [event_time], 108) AS [HH:MM]
        ,[location_id]
        ,[start_time_shift_1]
        ,[stop_time_shift_1]
        ,[start_time_shift_2]
        ,[stop_time_shift_2]
        ,[start_time_shift_3]
        ,[stop_time_shift_3]
      FROM [dbo].[testData]
      )
      
      SELECT
      [item_id]
      ,[event_time]
      ,[HH:MM]
      ,[location_id]
      ,CASE 
            WHEN [location_id] = '100' THEN(
                CASE WHEN [HH:MM] BETWEEN [start_time_shift_1] AND [stop_time_shift_1] THEN 'Shift_1'
                     WHEN [HH:MM] BETWEEN [start_time_shift_2] AND [stop_time_shift_2] THEN 'Shift_2'
                     WHEN [HH:MM] BETWEEN [start_time_shift_3] AND [stop_time_shift_3] THEN 'Shift_3' END)      
            
            WHEN [location_id] = '200' THEN(
                CASE WHEN [HH:MM] BETWEEN [start_time_shift_1] AND [stop_time_shift_1] THEN 'Shift_1'
                     WHEN [HH:MM] BETWEEN [start_time_shift_2] AND [stop_time_shift_2] THEN 'Shift_2' END)
      END AS [pass]
      ,[start_time_shift_1]
      ,[stop_time_shift_1]
      ,[start_time_shift_2]
      ,[stop_time_shift_2]
      ,[start_time_shift_3]
      ,[stop_time_shift_3]
      
      FROM CTE1
      WHERE [location_id] = '100'
```

Comment: I would like to match an event within the right ’shift’. But the issue is that the shifts are spanning over 00:00 for some shifts (i.e between 22:00 - 07:58 for example). Can this be calculated some other way perhaps? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes exactly, the start date should be the event_time date.

Comment: by using the event_time date and concanate that shift homes into a datetime then do your case comparisons.   however, if the person is late for his shift then the start date could be into the next day.  Therefore, the results are not deterministic.  Not enough data

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that while it's simple to check for a value being between (HH:MM)1 and (HH:MM)2 as long as (HH:MM)1 < (HH:MM)2, but if that's not the case, then there is some difficulty.

It seems that you have two cases to cope with:

## (HH:MM)1 < (HH:MM)2

In this case you can use the normal `between` operator as you did.

## (HH:MM)1 > (HH:MM)2

your date is

- `>=` (HH:MM)1
- `OR`
- `<=` (HH:MM)2